# How to check whether the content in DIV has loaded?

Tags: html, ajax, web-applications

The content in DIV is loaded after a button is pressed on the same page.
The button send a request to the server, a python file, the files returns some text that is loaded in `div` part of the page using Ajax.

I actually want a "loading image" to be there till the `div` content is not loaded.

```
<form id="f1">
    <textarea name="textcontent" id="styled" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/test.py")' type="button" value="Show" class="blue"/>
    <br>
    <div id="qList"></div>
</form>
```

The text returned by the server is to be loaded in `div` whose id is "qList".

Please help!

Comment: I think is better if you manage the _on loading_ situation using the callbacks from the _ajax caller_. I don't know wich _callbacks_ the object `JavaScript:xmlhttpPost` has but I'm sure it has some to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="qList"><!-- insert loading image code here --></div>
```

When your `xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/test.py")` is done, it can replace the loading image with the content it wants.